# all-delete-orphan grails 2.5.5

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Can you add a child to the parent on its ParentController edit action?

when i'm trying to add child in the editAction I got this kind of error

> Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : Error executing tag : Error executing tag : Error executing tag : Error executing tag : Error executing tag : Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.webbfontaine.elicense.License.fees; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Comment: can you share the code of your editAction ?

Comment: Please show the code you are trying